# struts 1.2 csrf guard with tokenperpage

Tags: java, csrf, struts-1, csrf-protection, owasp

struts 1.2 csrf guard with tokenperpage

Hi,  I have a struts 1.2 application with csrfguard (version 1.0) implemented with tokenperpage=false i.e, token per session. And csrfguard working fine with token  per session.

In owasp.csrfguard.properties file:

org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenRedirectPage=unauth.jsp

org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=false

In the jsp:
html:form action="/Login" styleId="loginForm"
input type="hidden" property="CSRFTOKEN" name="CSRFTOKEN" value="${sessionScope['CSRFTOKEN']}"

The above case is working fine...

Right now i am trying for tokenperpage true..

In owasp.csrfguard.properties file:

org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenRedirectPage=unauth.jsp

org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=ture

In the jsp:
html:form action="/Login" styleId="loginForm"
input type="hidden" property="CSRFTOKEN" name="csrf:token-name/" value="csrf:token-value uri="/Login"/"

The above is generating the token in the form's hidden field, but on submitting the form the page is navigating to NewTokenRedirectPage configured in the properties file... I expect it should navigate to the jsp mapped in strut-config.xml for the action Login... but its navigating to NewTokenRedirectPage....

Someone help me to figure out the issue...

Thanks in advance...